# Is it possible to enumerate/scan available USB ports with Boost Asio C++ library

Tags: c++, windows, boost, serial-port, boost-asio

I want to use Boost Asio library to connect my USB device. It works. Now I want to enumerate/scan all possible USB devices to see which one can be used. Is that possible in Boost Asio library? I haven't found any function nor information about that.

This is the most closed scenario to find USB ports. But not sure if it's a proper solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::serial_port port(io);


    char portName[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        try {
            sprintf_s(portName, "COM%i", i);
            port.open(portName);
            if (port.is_open()) {
                printf("Port COM%i is a possible USB port\n", i);
                port.close();
            }
        }
        catch (...) {
            printf("Port COM%i is not a possible USB port\n", i);
        }
        
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a feature of the library.

Since you are looking for windows, consider using WMI interface to enumerate serial ports. E.g. in C# code:

```
try
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
        new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI",
        "SELECT * FROM MSSerial_PortName");

    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("InstanceName: {0}", queryObj["InstanceName"]);
        Console.WriteLine("PortName: {0}", queryObj["PortName"]);
    }
}
catch (ManagementException e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
}
```

Comment: If I know the vendor ID and product ID, can I find the COM port then?

Comment: Probably. That's a different question though. Looks like [this page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f3003f55-aecf-41da-b0a8-1b5e8bf99894/extracting-serial-number-vendor-id-and-product-id-from-usb-pendrive-using-c?forum=netfxbcl) shows an example. You can probably bake the conditions into the search query

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Then I know that I cannot scan the ports in Boost Asio library.